# Bad access error after taking photo

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

   //added other code

     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Photo added to  library" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
}
```

After taking photo in my app which shows "Bad access Error".If i remove Alertbox it is fine.what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please post your full error message..that will help you and somebody else to...

Comment: if you are in multi-threaded environment .. use performSelectorOnMainThread instead of performSelectorInBackground.

Comment: thanks.it is working fine.Why it is not working with performSelectorInBackground?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

use `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: i am running entire code in background method.Does it reason for cause?

Comment: @user2067403 You mean you are calling a UI method in a background thread?